# Table View cell show a list Column wise or row wise in a single table

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

We need to show the list of option that user can select the submit the answer, For that we have used table view cell but in that we can able show the option in a list view but here need to show the option in a grid view if the options count increase above 10.

Here I have attached the sample layout image, please check it. I tried many ways to overcome this but I can’t.

[image: in]  [image]

Comment: Use CollectionView

Answer (score 1):

The **UITableView** was designed for vertical displaying only, so unless you are using some weird methods to display cells as a grid "which may decrease performance"

The best solution is to use a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html) which can be used to represent content in any way.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use **UICollectionView** for your purpose. **sizeForItemAtIndexPath** is a delegate method for collection view in that you can set the cell size. If option count is less than 10 set **frameWidth** as the cell width else **frameWidth/2** as  cell width

```
   - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (optionCount<10) {
     return  CGSizeMake( (self.collectionview.frame.size.width-8, yourHeight);

      }
    else
      {
    return  CGSizeMake( ((self.collectionview.frame.size.width)/2-8, yourHeight);
    }
 }
```